# using forEach() to find price of items in cat in the backend

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to implement a payment gateway system into a project that I'm working on, and I need to get the cart total in the backend instead of just in the frontend. I'm trying to do this with `forEach()` and `reduce()`. The part that I am struggling with is filtering through `_id`s from all of my products to then find the `_ids` associated with my items in my cart (`cartInfo`), and then from there getting the price of the items whose `_ids` match the `_ids` of the items in the cart. Below, I have included what I have so far. I would really appreciate any help or guidance on how to do this. Thank you!

```
const total = products.forEach(x => {
    if (x._id === cartInfo._id) {
      const itemsTotal = x.price * cartInfo.qty
      }
    })
  
const sum = itemsTotal.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
```

`products` is an array of all of the products and `cartInfo` contains the `_id`s and `qty`s of each of the products in the cart.

Example of cartInfo:

```
0: {_id: '624bc7fe0f91078261ab6529', qty: 1}
1: {_id: '624bc8240f91078261ab6531', qty: 2}
```

Example of products:

```
0: {_id: '624bc7fe0f91078261ab6529', name: sample 1, price: 30, countInStock: 10}
1: {_id: '624bc8240f91078261ab6531', name: sample 2, price 10, countInStock: 4}
2: {_id: '624bc1a50f91078261ab650d', name: sample 3, price 15, countInStock: 1}
3: {_id: '62562017645f1882e45adc32', name: sample 4, price 20, countInStock: 7}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So specifically using the methods you want to use. You could do something like so. The main thing I change though is iterating the cart first and then using the find method to match the cart id to the product id.

```
const cart = [{
    _id: '624bc7fe0f91078261ab6529',
    qty: 1
  },
  {
    _id: '624bc8240f91078261ab6531',
    qty: 2
  }
]

const products = [{
    _id: '624bc7fe0f91078261ab6529',
    name: 'sample 1',
    price: 30,
    countInStock: 10
  },
  {
    _id: '624bc8240f91078261ab6531',
    name: 'sample 2',
    price: 10,
    countInStock: 4
  },
  {
    _id: '624bc1a50f91078261ab650d',
    name: 'sample 3',
    price: 15,
    countInStock: 1
  },
  {
    _id: '62562017645f1882e45adc32',
    name: 'sample 4',
    price: 20,
    countInStock: 7
  }
]

const cartTotals = [];
cart.forEach((product) => {
  const matchedProduct = products.find(element => element._id === product._id);
  if (matchedProduct) {
    cartTotals.push(product.qty * matchedProduct.price);
  }
});

console.log(cartTotals)

const totalAmount = cartTotals.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);

console.log(totalAmount);
```

Answer (score 1):

For readability and loop optimisation, I prefer the simple `for...of` statement  for these kinds of scenarios:

```
let cartInfo = [
  {
    _id: `624bc7fe0f91078261ab6529`,
    qty: 1
  },
  {
    _id: `624bc8240f91078261ab6531`,
    qty: 2
  },
];

let products = [
  {
    _id: `624bc7fe0f91078261ab6529`,
    name: `sample 1`,
    price: 30,
    countInStock: 10
  },
  {
    _id: `624bc8240f91078261ab6531`,
    name: `sample 2`,
    price: 10,
    countInStock: 4
  },
  {
    _id: `624bc1a50f91078261ab650d`,
    name: `sample 3`,
    price: 15,
    countInStock: 1
  },
  {
    _id: `62562017645f1882e45adc32`,
    name: `sample 4`,
    price: 20,
    countInStock: 7
  },
];

let cartTotalPrice = 0;

for (cartItem of cartInfo) {
  for (product of products) {
    if (cartItem._id === product._id) {
      cartTotalPrice += (product.price * cartItem.qty);
      break;
    };
  };
};

console.log(cartTotalPrice);
```

The readability aspect of this solution is subjective, but I just think this code looks a lot more human-friendly than methods and callback functions.

The `for...of` statements used here will also provide the ability to break-out of a given loop with the `break` statement. So in this context, if an item in the cart is matched to an item in products array in an iteration of the nested `for...of` loop, that same cart item won't be queried against the products array again in subsequent loops. With this specific dataset and solution, this brings the overall loops down from 8 to 3. You can probably imagine that with larger cart sizes and product catalogues, the performance benefits would be pretty significant.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a single forEach like this:

```
let total = 0;
cartInfo.forEach(productInCart => {
  const product = products.find(productExtended => productExtended.id === productInCart.id);
  total += product.price * productInCart.qty;
});
```

But I would suggest to store the product's price inside cartInfo, that way you will not need to access products at all when counting the total

Answer (score 0):

Try using reduce function

```
const total = cartInfo.reduce((totalValue, currentCartItem) => {
  const foundProduct = products.find(product => product._id === currentCartItem._id);
  if (foundProduct) {
    totalValue += foundProduct.price * currentCartItem.qty
 }
}, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example where you can get the subtotal for each item and then the total:

```js
const cartInfo = [
  {_id: '624bc7fe0f91078261ab6529', qty: 1},
  {_id: '624bc8240f91078261ab6531', qty: 2}
]

const products = [
  {_id: '624bc7fe0f91078261ab6529', name: 'sample 1', price: 30, countInStock: 10},
  {_id: '624bc8240f91078261ab6531', name: 'sample 2', price: 10, countInStock: 4},
  {_id: '624bc1a50f91078261ab650d', name: 'sample 3', price: 15, countInStock: 1},
  {_id: '62562017645f1882e45adc32', name: 'sample 4', price: 20, countInStock: 7}
]

let subtotals = cartInfo.map(({_id, qty}) => {
  return { _id, subtotal: qty * products.find(p => p._id === _id).price }
})

let total = subtotals.reduce((total, item) => item.subtotal + total, 0)

console.log('Subtotals:', subtotals)
console.log('Total:', total)
```